# Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. r было nullptr

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Реализация В-дерева, в функции Insert происходит исключение "Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. r было nullptr." Как я понимаю из-за того что узел создаётся null и крашится программа. Но в ++ я не силен будьте добры подскажите.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int Maxn = 10;
struct Node
{
    int n;
    int key[Maxn];
    Node* C[Maxn + 1];
    bool isleaf;
    Node(int n, bool is) :n(n), isleaf(is) {}
};

class Btree
{
private:
    int t;
    int h;
    Node* root;
    pair<Node*, int> Nsearch(Node* t, int k);
    void split(Node* x, int i, Node* y);
    void Insert_Nonfull(Node* x, int k);
    int Predecessor(Node* y); // Предшественник
    int Successor(Node* z); // Наследник
    // i-е ключевое слово x передается правому дочернему узлу
    void Shift_Right(Node* x, int i, Node* y, Node* z);
    // i-е ключевое слово x передается левому дочернему узлу
    void Shift_Left(Node* x, int i, Node* y, Node* z);
    void DeleteNon(Node* x, int k);
    // Объединить i-е ключевое слово y, z и x -> объединить в одно y
    void Merge(Node* x, int i, Node* y, Node* z);
public:
    pair<Node*, int> search(int k);
    Btree(int tt) { t = tt; h = 1; root = new Node(0, true); }
    Btree() {}
    void Insert(int k);
    void Delete(int k);
    void showNode(Node* t)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < t->n; i++)
            cout << t->key[i] << '\t';
        cout << endl;
    }
    Node* GetRoot() { return root; }
    int GetHeight() { return h; }
};

pair <Node*, int> Btree::Nsearch(Node* t, int k) 
{
    Node* r = root;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < t->n && t->key[i] < k) 
        i++;
    if (i < t->n && t->key[i] == k) // найдено
    {
        return pair<Node*, int>(t, i + 1);
    }
    else if (t->isleaf) // Не удалось найти
    {
        cout << k << "SF!!!\n";
        return pair<Node*, int>(nullptr, -1);
    }
    else
        return Nsearch(t->C[i], k); // Рекурсивный поиск
}
pair<Node*, int> Btree::search(int k)
{
    return Nsearch(root, k);
}

void Btree::split(Node* x, int i, Node* y)
{
    Node* z = new Node(t - 1, y->isleaf); // Новый узел
    y->n = t - 1; // Обновляем размер y
    for (int j = 0; j < t - 1; j++) // после t-1 вернуться к z
        z->key[j] = y->key[j + t];
    if (!y->isleaf)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < t; j++)
            z->C[j] = y->C[j + t];
    }
    for (int j = x->n; j > i; j--) 
    {
        x->key[j] = x->key[j - 1];
    }
    x->key[i] = y->key[t - 1];
    for (int j = x->n + 1; j > i + 1; j--) 
    {
        x->C[j] = x->C[j - 1];
    }
    x->C[i + 1] = z;
    x->n++;
}

// Вспомогательный процесс, запрос x не заполнен
void Btree::Insert_Nonfull(Node* x, int k)
{
    int i = x->n - 1;
    if (x->isleaf) // x листовой узел (не полный)
    {
        while (i >= 0 && k < x->key[i]) // Находим позицию вставки сзади, перемещаемся назад, чтобы скорректировать ключевое слово
        {
            x->key[i + 1] = x->key[i];
            i--;
        }
        x->key[i + 1] = k;
        x->n++;
    }
    else
    {
        while (i >= 0 && k < x->key[i]) 
            i--;
        i++; 
        if (x->C[i]->n == 2 * t - 1) // разделить
        {
            split(x, i, x->C[i]);
            if (k > x->key[i])
                i++;
        }
        Insert_Nonfull(x->C[i], k);
    }
}
void Btree::Insert(int k)
{
    Node* r = root;
    if (r->n == 2 * t - 1)
    {
        root = new Node(0, false);
        root->C[0] = r; 
        split(root, 0, r);
        h++;
        Insert_Nonfull(root, k);
    }
    else
        Insert_Nonfull(r, k);
}

int Btree::Predecessor(Node* y) // Предшественник
{
    Node* x = y;
    int i = x->n;
    while (!x->isleaf)
    {
        x = x->C[i];
        i = x->n;
    }
    return x->key[i - 1];
}
int Btree::Successor(Node* z) // наследник
{
    Node* x = z;
    while (!x->isleaf)
    {
        x = x->C[0];
    }
    return x->key[0];
}
// i-е ключевое слово x передается правому дочернему узлу
void Btree::Shift_Right(Node* x, int i, Node* y, Node* z) // i-1 - это индекс
{
    int j = z->n;
    while (j > 0)
    {
        z->key[j] = z->key[j - 1];
        j--;
    }
    z->key[0] = x->key[i - 1];
    x->key[i - 1] = y->key[y->n - 1];
    z->n++;
    if (!z->isleaf)
    {
        j = z->n;
        while (j > 0)
        {
            z->C[j] = z->C[j - 1];
        }
        z->C[0] = y->C[y->n];
    }
    y->n--;
}
// i-е ключевое слово x передается левому дочернему узлу
void Btree::Shift_Left(Node* x, int i, Node* y, Node* z) // i-1 - это индекс
{
    y->n++;
    y->key[y->n - 1] = x->key[i - 1];
    x->key[i - 1] = z->key[0];
    z->n--;
    int j = 0;
    while (j < z->n)
    {
        z->key[j] = z->key[j + 1];
        j++;
    }
    if (!z->isleaf)
    {
        y->C[y->n] = z->C[0];
        j = 0;
        while (j <= z->n)
        {
            z->C[j] = z->C[j + 1];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
void Btree::Merge(Node* x, int i, Node* y, Node* z) // i-1 - это индекс C ++
{
    y->n = 2 * t - 1;
    for (int j = t; j < 2 * t - 1; j++)
        y->key[j] = z->key[j - t];
    y->key[t - 1] = x->key[i - 1];
    if (!y->isleaf)
    {
        for (int j = t; j <= 2 * t - 1; j++)
            y->C[j] = z->C[j - t];
    }
    for (int j = i; j < x->n; j++)
        x->key[j - 1] = x->key[j];
    for (int j = i; j < x->n; j++)
        x->C[j] = x->C[j + 1];
    x->n--;
    delete z;
}
void Btree::DeleteNon(Node* x, int k)
{
    Node* y = nullptr;
    Node* z = nullptr;
    int i = 0;
    if (x->isleaf)                            //Case1
    {
        while (i < x->n && k>x->key[i])
        {
            i++;
        }
        if (k == x->key[i])
        {
            x->n--;
            for (int j = i; j < x->n; j++)
            {
                x->key[j] = x->key[j + 1];
            }
        }
        else cout << "DF!!!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while (i<x->n && k>x->key[i])
        {
            i++;
        }
        y = x->C[i];
        if (i < x->n)
            z = x->C[i + 1];
        if (k == x->key[i])                      //Case2
            if (y->n > t - 1)                    //Case2 a
            {
                int k0 = Predecessor(y);
                DeleteNon(y, k0);
                x->key[i] = k0;
            }
            else if (z->n > t - 1)               //Case2 b
            {
                int k0 = Successor(z);
                DeleteNon(z, k0);
                x->key[i] = k0;
            }
            else                                  //Case2 c
            {
                Merge(x, i + 1, y, z);
                DeleteNon(y, k);
            }
        else                                      //Case3
        {
            Node* p = nullptr;
            if (i > 0) 
                p = x->C[i - 1]; 
            if (y->n == t - 1)
            {
                if (i > 0 && p->n > t - 1)
                    Shift_Right(x, i, p, y); // i - это число, а не индекс Case3 a
                else if (i < x->n && z->n > t - 1)
                    Shift_Left(x, i + 1, y, z);
                else if (i > 0)
                {
                    Merge(x, i, p, y);            //Case3 b
                    y = p;
                }
                else
                    Merge(x, i + 1, y, z);
            }
            DeleteNon(y, k);
        }
    }
}
void Btree::Delete(int k)
{
    Node* r = root;
    if (r->n == 1)
    {
        Node* y = r->C[0];
        Node* z = r->C[1];
        if (y->n == t - 1 && z->n == t - 1)
        {
            Merge(r, 1, y, z);
            root = y;
            delete r;
            DeleteNon(y, k);
        }
        else
            DeleteNon(r, k);
    }
    else
        DeleteNon(r, k);
}

void main() {
    Btree t;
    t.Insert(1);
    t.showNode(t.search(1).first);
}
```

Сбой происходит здесь:

```
void Btree::Insert(int k)
{
    Node* r = root;
    if (r->n == 2 * t - 1) <<<<<<
    {
        root = new Node(0, false);
        root->C[0] = r; 
        split(root, 0, r);
        h++;
        Insert_Nonfull(root, k);
    }
    else
        Insert_Nonfull(r, k);
}
```

Скрин с ошибкой

[image: Скриншот сообщения об ошибке]

Comment: "Но в ++ я не силен" и этот код не соответствуют друг другу. Что за задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я студент, нужно реализовать В дерево, пытаюсь понять почему эта реализация не работает и как заставить работать

Comment: Этот код написан вами?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy нет код написан не мной, думаю это стоило указать, нашел его пока искал реализации с удалением узлов

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, ошибка была при инициализации дерева в main

```
void main() {
    Btree t;<<<<<
    t.Insert(1);
    t.showNode(t.search(1).first);
}
```

всего то нужно было

```
void main() {
    Btree t(1);<<<<
    t.Insert(1);
    t.showNode(t.search(1).first);
}
```

надеюсь кому то поможет но сомневаюсь